# Google earth repository

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, repository, 32-bit, google-earth

I use

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list'
```

then

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

then this what i got

```
    sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-earth-stable:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 100 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable/main google-earth-stable i386 6.1.0.4738-r0
  404  Not Found [IP: 216.58.198.206 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/pool/main/g/google-earth-stable/google-earth-stable_6.1.0.4738-r0_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 216.58.198.206 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

then i use this to get that

```
  sudo apt update
[sudo] password for ubuntuman2: 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Get:1 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://download.videolan.org  InRelease                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://download.videolan.org  Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib amd64 Packages               
Hit http://download.videolan.org  Release                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb InRelease                          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:2 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [384 kB]        
Hit http://download.videolan.org  Sources                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib i386 Packages                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://download.videolan.org  Packages                                     
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:3 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,360 B] 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Get:4 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [169 kB]    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en_US            
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Get:5 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,531 B] 
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-en_US                            
Get:6 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [913 kB] 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-en                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                           
Get:7 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:8 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [387 kB]
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US             
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en                
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en               
Get:9 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [15.0 kB]
Get:10 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [872 kB] 
Get:11 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:12 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [389 kB]
Get:13 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.5 kB]
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Fetched 3,254 kB in 17s (186 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

so any solution for the broken repository pls ?

Comment: Is there a reason you just can't download the deb from Google directly?

Comment: yes i want the right repository if u don't mind :)

Comment: Okay, let me try yet a few more things, because I'm having issues finding the right repo right now.

Comment: take your time  my friend

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: check it out above

Comment: Strange. I can't reproduce this bug. I'll go try to talk to some other people.

Answer (score 2):

Google no longer maintains repositories at dl.google.com. You either need to download the software directly at https://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html, or use Synaptic to install the `googleearth-package` that will allow you to build your own Google Earth installer.